# MSBuild hangs while copying files

Tags: msbuild, web-deployment-project

Consider this command line

```
msbuild R:\Build\trunk\19973\Deploy-Admin\Deploy-Admin.wdproj /p:Configuration="Release" /property:OutputPath=R:\Build\trunk\19973\!Output\Admin
```

What we see here is the msbuild compiler building a Web Deployment Project with some parameters manipulating the configuration and the OutputPath.

Everything worked fine. The time the MSBuild took to compile was always around 8 minutes.

Something happened then. The MSBuild now takes 30 minutes to compile the project and it seems it's doing "something" just for 22 minutes.

It was then when I noticed that the MSBuild is working 2 minutes well until it gets to the part of copying files. The MSBuild output stops outputing anything and I see the csc.exe compiler taking some percentage of the processor.

This takes approx these 22 minutes, the msbuild output unfreezes after that and the compiler finishes.

This is how the last lines from the output look like.

```
ResolveAssemblyReferences:
 Copying file from "R:\Build\trunk\19973\!Ouput\Admin\it\Utils.resources.dll" to "R:\Build\trunk\19973\Admin\Bin\Utils.resources.dll".
 Copying file from "R:\Build\trunk\19973\!Ouput\Admin\ru\Utils.resources.dll" to "R:\Build\trunk\19973\Admin\Bin\Utils.resources.dll".
 Copying file from "R:\Build\trunk\19973\!Ouput\Admin\ru-RU\Utils.resources.dll" to "R:\Build\trunk\19973\Admin\Bin\Utils.resources.dll".
 Copying file from "R:\Build\trunk\19973\!Ouput\Admin\sk\Utils.resources.dll" to "R:\Build\trunk\19973\Admin\Bin\Utils.resources.dll".
 Copying file from "R:\Build\trunk\19973\!Ouput\Admin\tt-RU\Utils.resources.dll" to "R:\Build\trunk\19973\Admin\Bin\Utils.resources.dll".
 Copying fil
```

MsBuild won't even finish the line output until 22 minutes later, completing the whole process after 30 minutes.

*Note: VS2010 compiler is working still well, taking approx 8 minutes to compile*

Has that ever happened to anyone? We've been trying to figure out the changes from the commit from which the build started to take so long but that particular commit wasn't anyhow special nor related to anything that could affect the compiler (no namespaces and no assembly references has been changed).

Comment: Add `/v:diag` switch to generate diagnostic log. Also consider `/m:n` where n=number of processors to increase build speed.

Comment: See if someone put a "**" (recursive) wildcard into some operation that occurrs repeatedly, which would cause a potentially deep recursive search.  Use /consoleloggerparameters:PerformanceSummary to see tasks that may be improperly tuned.

Comment: Is `R:` a mapped network share?